# Type is not assignable to generic type

Tags: typescript

Why doesn't this compile?

```
interface ITest { ... }    

class Test implements ITest { ... }

class Factory<T extends ITest> {
    constructor(private _Test: typeof Test) { }

    create(): T {
        return new this._Test();
    }
}
```

It gives `Type 'Test' is not assignable to type 'T'. (property) Factory<T extends ITest>._Test: new () => Test`.

How I could make it work is by either

```
create(): ITest
```

or through

```
private _Test: any
```

Both would not really be communicating (code-wise) what I am after. Any way in which I could make it work?

Comment: How you suppose this to work? How are you going to use factory? Can you provide some example code?

Comment: Hi @SergeyYarotskiy, why I thought this would work I described in my comment to Rico Kahler. I mistakenly assumed that `typeof CertainClass` could be used to describe the type of `CertainClass` which implements `ICertainClass`. It worked in other classes without generics involved, but as soon as I started to define a generic type on my Factory, it pointed out a misunderstanding about the type system on my side.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Why doesn't this compile?

It doesn't compile because the type of `_Test` is `typeof Test`. That can be confusing so let me try to break that down:

---

Typescript add "types" to the world of javascript giving you a way to say "I expect this object to have all these properties and operations available to them.". In an essence, this is all a [type system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_system) does.

Typescript has the `typeof` operator which acts like a [type query](https://blog.mariusschulz.com/2016/05/31/type-queries-and-typeof-in-typescript) as a way to get the "type" *from an instantiated object* when used on the right side of a type annotation (the `:`). The `typeof` gives you a way to say "whatever properties and operations that this object has, I want to capture those and reuse them to check the type of another object".

Here is an example of using this `typeof` operator.

```
let myObject = {
    a: 'a string',
    b: 5,
    c: false
};

// notice that the `typeof` operator is on the right of the `:`
function takesATypeOfMyObject(obj: typeof myObject) {
    // highlight over `a`, `b`, or `c` to see their type
    obj.a // (property) a: string
    obj.b // (property) b: number
    obj.c // (property) c: boolean
}
```

`myObject` is a normal javascript object literal. The function `takesATypeOfMyObject` is a function with one parameter `obj` with the type annotation of `typeof myObject`. This function is saying that is can take in any object with the same properties as the object `myObject`.

This is not to be confused with javascript's [`typeof`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/typeof) operator that only returns a string. Typescript's `typeof` operator is part of it's type system. Remember that when typescript is compiled to javascript, the types and type annotations go away.

---

Another important thing to understand is how classes in typescript work. Classes are kind of a doubled-edged-sword. In typescript, classes act as both:

- a type - as in a definition of properties and operations you can perform on an object. As well as
- a constructor - as in a concrete `function` you can call with `new` to get the mentioned type

It might be tempting to using the type annotation `typeof MyClass` but this is most likely not what you intended.

Consider the example below:

```
// define a class Animal
// this creates the type definition of `Animal` as well as
// the constructor to create an `Animal`
class Animal {
    makeNosie() { return 'grrr'; }
}

// use the constructor to create an object of type `Animal`
let myAnimal = new Animal();
// now `myAnimal` has an inferred type of `Animal`

// declare an object to of type `Animal` but instead of using
// the `Animal` constructor, just define an object literal that
// conforms to the type of Animal
let dog: Animal = {
    makeNosie: () => 'woof'
};
// the type of dog has been declared explicitly and typescript
// just checks to see if it conforms to the type
```

So hopefully you see that if you want an object to conform to the type that a class creates, you don't use the `typeof` operator, you just say "Animal", not `typeof Animal`.

But that brings us to the question: what if you did that?

Remember that the `typeof` operator tries to capture the type to be reused. Since `class`es define both a type and a `new`able function to create an object of that type, **what `typeof Animal` is actually doing is querying the type of the constructor of Animal**.

---

Okay so now we can finally dig in your code to understand why it isn't compiling. Below is the original code you pasted:

> ```
> interface ITest { }    
>
> class Test implements ITest { }
>
> class Factory<T extends ITest> {
>     constructor(private _Test: typeof Test) { }
>
>     create(): T {
>         return new this._Test();
>     }
> }
> ```

Take a look at the `constructor` of `Factory`. What you're saying with this code is that "The `constructor` of my class `Factory` takes any Object that conforms to the constructor of Test. That's one pretty complicated type (and probably not what you intended).

Instead try this code:

```
interface ITest { }    

class Test implements ITest { }

class Factory<T extends ITest> {
    constructor(private _Test: new() => T) { }

    create(): T {
        return new this._Test();
    }
}
```

The type description of `_Test` has been changed to `new() => T` which is saying that "the constructor of Factory takes in any `new`able function that returns a the type `T`".

Hopefully that's what you've intended.

I hope I've help you solved your problem as well as show you how powerful typescript is. Typescript is trying to do a very ambitious and crazy thing: add full types to any possible javascript. I think they're doing a great job.

Comment: Thank you for your extensive answer! I am using TS with a lot of joy, but still learning and not entirely proficient. Your solution indeed solved my issue. Why I was confused was that in cases where I injected non-instantiated classes with `typeof Test` it worked, but that was outside the scope of generics (thus `create` would just be typed to return `ITest`). So it kind of hid an underlying misunderstanding of me, which you pointed out. I will have to review those cases with your provided information. Thanks again!

Comment: I cannot edit my comment anymore, but `new(...) => T` indeed is what I intended, and describes exactly what I meant to say: a newable function which returns a type.